# Getting error:"Input string was not in a correct format" while installing PagedList.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am not able to understand why this error is occurring whilst installing PagedList.MVC in NugetPackage.

> Input string was not in a correct format

Has anybody came across this issue? Please help me to install it.

[image: Error while installing PagedList.MVC]